# how do i add each fieldname and their respective value into one json object dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, forms

I am new to React js , in my one component i am setting field name dynamically , it comes from api to redux store then from their it come into my component ,

I want to make one array that i can pass to API in Post method which will   have key value pair  ,

**This is how i am building dynamic fields**

```
        <Panel.Body key={index}>
        {
        this.buildTemplate(item,index)
        }
        </Panel.Body>
```

In buildTemplate() i am rendering html elements using if else statement and with each element i am using function that can give change state of that field.

```
 if (['url', 'text', 'title'].indexOf(role) >= 0) {
        return (
            <FormControl  type={role.toLowerCase()} placeholder={role} onChange={this.handleShareholderNameChange(id,item.label)}/>
        )
    } else if (['date'].indexOf(role) >= 0){
        return (
            <DatePicker id="from-date-dt" onChange={this.handleShareholderNameChange(id,item)}/>
        )
```

In my handleShareholderNameChange

```
handleShareholderNameChange(id,item){
   var obj={}
   var array= []
   if(obj.id===undefined || obj[fieldName] === undefined){
       obj.id = id;
       obj[fieldName] = evt.target.value;
       array.push(obj);
   }
   if(obj.id === id){
       obj.id = id;
       obj[fieldName]= evt.target.value;
       array.push(obj);
   }
   console.log("array",array);
}
```

I want each input data with field name like below..

```
  array = [  { id:1, name:'abc', url:'xyz' },  { id:2, name:'abcd',
 url:'xyz2sqssqsq' }  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to dynamicly load in all JSON attributes, the way you build it looks fine. But there always comes a moment that you have to type all the attributes by hand. The most dynamic way to load json objects into a React component is with [ReactTable](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme).

Then you can do something like this:

```
<ReactTable data={[  { id:1, name:'abc', url:'xyz' },  { id:2, name:'abcd',
url:'xyz2sqssqsq' }  ]}
columns={[{"Header": "id", accessor: "id"}, {"Header": "name", accessor: "name"}, {"Header": "url", accessor: "url"}]}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response..  @HarryStylesheet

Comment: You're welcome. ReactTable is really helpfull for a quick nice layout for a table. Would you mind marking my answer as the answer? Thanks in advance!